How to sort/order query based on presence in array in laravel?
I want to sort/order a query in laravel. For example I have a model where 'id' ranges from 1 to 100. And I have an array of ids of selected model elements eg. [1,3,12,32,...].
I want to sort my model based on its id being present in the array. For ascending order the elements not present in the array will come first and for descending order the element present in the array will come first.
I have tried to use callback function in orderBy() clause but it doesn't work.

You can directly order by IN in your query
$ids = [1,3,12,32];
Model::query()
    ->orderBy(\DB::raw('id IN('.implode(',', $ids).')'), 'desc')
    ->paginate(); // or get()

A safer way would be
Model::query()
    ->orderBy(\DB::raw('id IN(:ids)'), 'desc')
    ->addBinding(['ids' => implode(',', $ids)])
    ->paginate(); // or get()


Or using orderByRaw() as @Tarun suggested to avoid using the DB facade
Model::query()
    ->orderByRaw('id IN(:ids) desc', ['ids' => implode(',', $ids)])
    ->paginate(); // or get()

